# Cannot installing PEAR mail on Ubuntu

Tags: php, email, pear

I don't know if anyone has experienced this before. I was trying to install PEAR Mail so that I can use external server to send emails. But i keep getting error message when I enter the following command:

```
:~# pear install Mail Mail_Mime
```

Here is the error message:

```
Warning: mkdir(): File exists in System.php on line 277
PHP Warning:  mkdir(): File exists in /usr/share/php/System.php on line 277

Warning: mkdir(): Not a directory in System.php on line 277
PHP Warning:  mkdir(): Not a directory in /usr/share/php/System.php on line 277
Did not download optional dependencies: pear/Net_SMTP, use --alldeps to download automatically
pear/Mail can optionally use package "pear/Net_SMTP" (version >= 1.4.1)

Warning: mkdir(): File exists in System.php on line 277
PHP Warning:  mkdir(): File exists in /usr/share/php/System.php on line 277

Warning: mkdir(): Not a directory in System.php on line 277
PHP Warning:  mkdir(): Not a directory in /usr/share/php/System.php on line 277
download directory "/build/buildd/php5-5.3.2/pear-build-download" is not writeable.  Change download_dir config variable to a writeable dir
Error: cannot download "pear/Mail"

Warning: mkdir(): File exists in System.php on line 277
PHP Warning:  mkdir(): File exists in /usr/share/php/System.php on line 277

Warning: mkdir(): Not a directory in System.php on line 277
PHP Warning:  mkdir(): Not a directory in /usr/share/php/System.php on line 277
download directory "/build/buildd/php5-5.3.2/pear-build-download" is not writeable.  Change download_dir config variable to a writeable dir
Error: cannot download "pear/Mail_Mime"
Download failed
install failed
```

Is there anything I'm doing wrong? I'm working on Ubuntu.

```
<?php

  require_once "Mail.php";

 $from = "Sandra Sender <info@me.org>";
 $to = "Ramona Recipient <some@somedomain.com>";
 $subject = "Hi!";
 $body = "Hi,\n\nHow are you?";

 $host = "ssl://xxx.xxx.xxx";
 $port = "465";
 $username = "me@domain.org";
 $password = "password";

 $headers = array ('From' => $from,
   'To' => $to,
   'Subject' => $subject);
 $smtp = Mail::factory('smtp',
   array ('host' => $host,
     'port' => $port,
     'auth' => true,
     'username' => $username,
     'password' => $password));

 $mail = $smtp->send($to, $headers, $body);

 if (PEAR::isError($mail)) {
   echo("<p>" . $mail->getMessage() . "</p>");
  } else {
   echo("<p>Message successfully sent!</p>");
  } 
 ?>
```

Any help would be very appreciated.

**Update:**
Running with -alldeps did not help as well
:~# pear install --alldeps Mail Mail_Mime

```
Warning: mkdir(): File exists in System.php on line 277
PHP Warning:  mkdir(): File exists in /usr/share/php/System.php on line 277

Warning: mkdir(): Not a directory in System.php on line 277
PHP Warning:  mkdir(): Not a directory in /usr/share/php/System.php on line 277
WARNING: "pear/Auth_SASL" is deprecated in favor of "pear/Auth_SASL2"

Warning: mkdir(): File exists in System.php on line 277
PHP Warning:  mkdir(): File exists in /usr/share/php/System.php on line 277

Warning: mkdir(): Not a directory in System.php on line 277
PHP Warning:  mkdir(): Not a directory in /usr/share/php/System.php on line 277
download directory "/build/buildd/php5-5.3.2/pear-build-download" is not writeable.  Change download_dir config variable to a writeable dir
Error: cannot download "pear/Mail"

Warning: mkdir(): File exists in System.php on line 277
PHP Warning:  mkdir(): File exists in /usr/share/php/System.php on line 277

Warning: mkdir(): Not a directory in System.php on line 277
PHP Warning:  mkdir(): Not a directory in /usr/share/php/System.php on line 277
download directory "/build/buildd/php5-5.3.2/pear-build-download" is not writeable.  Change download_dir config variable to a writeable dir
Error: cannot download "pear/Mail_Mime"

Warning: mkdir(): File exists in System.php on line 277
PHP Warning:  mkdir(): File exists in /usr/share/php/System.php on line 277

Warning: mkdir(): Not a directory in System.php on line 277
PHP Warning:  mkdir(): Not a directory in /usr/share/php/System.php on line 277
download directory "/build/buildd/php5-5.3.2/pear-build-download" is not writeable.  Change download_dir config variable to a writeable dir
Error: cannot download "pear/Net_SMTP"

Warning: mkdir(): File exists in System.php on line 277
PHP Warning:  mkdir(): File exists in /usr/share/php/System.php on line 277

Warning: mkdir(): Not a directory in System.php on line 277
PHP Warning:  mkdir(): Not a directory in /usr/share/php/System.php on line 277
download directory "/build/buildd/php5-5.3.2/pear-build-download" is not writeable.  Change download_dir config variable to a writeable dir
Error: cannot download "pear/Net_Socket"

Warning: mkdir(): File exists in System.php on line 277
PHP Warning:  mkdir(): File exists in /usr/share/php/System.php on line 277

Warning: mkdir(): Not a directory in System.php on line 277
PHP Warning:  mkdir(): Not a directory in /usr/share/php/System.php on line 277
download directory "/build/buildd/php5-5.3.2/pear-build-download" is not writeable.  Change download_dir config variable to a writeable dir
Error: cannot download "pear/Auth_SASL"
Download failed
install failed
```

Comment: Try the thing PEAR is hinting you: `--alldeps`. So `pear install --alldeps Mail Mail_Mime`

Comment: Thanks Samuel, it's still spilling out error message.

Comment: Update your post and show the messages with the --alldeps call

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you have the download directory set to /build/buildd/php5-5.3.2/pear-build-download which is unwritable.

So you need to make it writable by using chmod:

```
# chmod -R 777 /build/buildd/php5-5.3.2/pear-build-download
```

It is even possible that setting in your pear config is a legacy from some previous release of your system, so you may need to recreate that directory structure, and then do the chmod:

```
# mkdir -p /build/buildd/php5-5.3.2/pear-build-download
```

Comment: Thanks. I've switched to PHPMailer - it's a lot easier to install and use.